# Iterate Mongodb Collection in pug/jade template

Tags: node.js, mongodb, pug

How do you pass a MongoDB collection to a .pug template?

I have this function that gets a mongodb collection named Test.

```
function get(req, res) {
    mongo.GetSort({}, {state: 1, name: 1}, 'Test')
        .then(function (list) {
            res.send(list);
        });
 }
```

How would I pass this to a pug template? I try to

`| console.log(Test)` in the pug template but the object Test does not exist.

I have `test.js` and `test.pug` in my directory. I tried searching for my question but most results involved using Express.js. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know where you get `GetSort` from? or what a `Tailwater` is? and you say without involving Express (because `function get(req, res){ res.send(...` sure looks like a signature express function, so you have me a little bit confused.)

Anyway, here is the simplest example I could come up with without any hint of express:

```
const compiledFunction = require('pug').compileFile('template.pug');
require('mongodb')
  .connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/')
  .then(mongo=>{
    mongo
      .db('somedb')
      .collection('somecollection')
      .find({})
      .toArray()
      .then(list=> {
        // You just pass your data into the function
        const html = compiledFunction({list: list}); 
        console.log(html);
        mongo.close();
    });    
});
```

And a `template.pug` along those lines:

```
html
  head
    title something
  body
    each item in list
      div= item.title
```

The thing is, express does most templating under the hood. So using express would likely make it cleaner.

So if you have express, you want to follow the documentation: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html

```
app.set('view engine', 'pug'); //Tell express you want to use pug.

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   const list = ... // 
   res.render('template', { list : list });
})
```

This would do the same thing as the example above AND ALSO send the html to the clients browser (which is express' thing after all).

Did I miss something?

Comment: I'm sorry - formatted my question poorly. I was changing variable names to make the question easier to understand and I forgot to change Tailwater to test. GetSort is a function I wrote that connects to a MongoDB and gets a collection name. Thank you for your answer, it's very helpful. I'll see where that gets me and update my post soon!